# React application won't deploy to Heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, heroku-cli

I have created a React application with a back-end using Node. For some reason, I cannot seem to push to Heroku successfully. I've added the following scripts to my package.json file in the root of my repository:

```
"scripts": {
"client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
"start": "node server.js",
"server": "nodemon server.js",
"client": "npm start --prefix client",
"dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
"heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix }
```

When I run `heroku logs --tail`, it tells me the build was successful but then throws this error:

```
2020-02-06T03:59:24.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-02-06T03:59:30.128450+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command bin/boot
2020-02-06T03:59:32.080167+00:00 app[web.1]: ls: cannot access '/app/build/static/js/*.js': No such file or directory
2020-02-06T03:59:32.080964+00:00 app[web.1]: Error injecting runtime env: bundle not found '/app/build/static/js/*.js'. See: https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack/blob/master/README.md#user-content-custom-bundle-location
```

What is this trying to tell me? Obviously, there is some file that hasn't been found or isn't there but what is it's significance? How do I fix this?

Here is the full code: https://github.com/caseycling/portfolio

Comment: Can you try changing "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client (Add `client` after --prefix in the build command in heroku-postbuild)

Comment: Oops, I mistyped my scripts. I already have it set to that